# Cortex M - Atomicity of IRQ disabling

Tags: assembly, arm, cortex-m, atomic

I've spent hours trying to answer my question, but could not find any satisfying answer.

Since ARM Cortex-M cores does not have any instruction to read the state of global interupt mask (PRIMASK register) and immediately disabling it, all frameworks are using the following sequence of two instructions:

```
mrs r0, PRIMASK ; Read current state
cpsid i         ; Mask IRQs
```

But there is no explanation, why this piece of code is considered atomic... What happens when the IRQ comes in between the execution of this two instructions and the IRQ handler changes the state of PRIMASK? Like

```
mrs r0, PRIMASK ; Read current state
; Some weird IRQ handling happens here and changes PRIMASK
cpsid i         ; Mask IRQs
```

Since this code is widely used, I suspect that this situation should never happen by (architecture?) design. Could somebody please explain to me why? :-) Thanks!

Comment: I think it would be very weird for an ISR to change PRIMASK without restoring it upon return to whatever was interrupted.  If an ISR enabled PRIMASK when it was otherwise disabled, that would be like turning off interrupts potentially on the main thread/process (without telling them), and bad things would happen.  Thus, I don't think this sequence does needs to be atomic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What happens when the IRQ comes in between the execution of this two instructions and the IRQ handler changes the state of PRIMASK?

The program will randomly lock up, as this would also break most other "wait for interrupt" methods (like `volatile` variables).

Remember that an interrupt can only occur if it is *not* masked, so the interrupt handler could only ever *disable* interrupts. But disabling interrupts globally will also prevent other interrupts from fireing - and the code waiting for some hardware interaction usually does *not* re-enable interrups randomly.

That is why an interrupt handler is considered br0ken when it modifies `PRIMASK` or `FAULTMASK`without restoring it on exception return.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. So the conclusion is that it is not atomic and does not need to be since IRQ should not leave the flage changed upon return. There probably are rare cases where this behaviour could be leveraged, but they falls into some "hacky" category... Thanks for clarification! :-)

Comment: Note that in an RTOS environment it's entirely possible that one task preempts another between these two instructions and then disables interrupts.  But for control to then return to the first task without the second having re-enabled interrupts would itself typically require some trickery, so it's a similar hacky situation to the ISR case.  (In fact, RTOSs generally severely restrict which APIs can be called with interrupts disabled, specifically for reasons like this.)